# HTTP 500 Internal error - throw explicitly in webservices

Tags: web-services, http

I am working on a web services application. I have a requirement to throw HTTP 500 error through my application for some test purposes. I use HTTPConnector class of apache to connect to various web services and I need to throw HTTP 500 to test something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your questions is not precise enough (e.g. programming language missing). In case you use Java I'd implement this as a [Servlet filter](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/).
In the filter you can then call [response.sendError(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29).

Comment: I found another way to return 502 instead of 500, which is fine by me.Thanks.